# How to use GResource to load an icon in Gtk3

Tags: c, icons, gtk3

This is my .gresource.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
    <gresource prefix="/org/readaratus/decoder">
        <file alias="app_icon">icon192.png</file>
    </gresource>
</gresources>
```

I wrote this code to set the icon:

```
gtk_window_set_icon_from_file(GTK_WINDOW(ui.main_window),
                              "resource:///org/readaratus/decoder/app_icon",
                              NULL);
```

Which fails with the following warning:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading icon from file 'resource:///org/readaratus/decoder/app_icon':
    Failed to open file 'resource:///org/readaratus/decoder/app_icon': No such file or directory
```

But if I query the resources bundle, it reports an object with 3631 bytes:

```
gsize size;
if(g_resources_get_info("/org/readaratus/decoder/app_icon",
                        G_RESOURCE_LOOKUP_FLAGS_NONE,
                        &size, NULL, NULL))
{
    g_print("app_icon size: %ld\n", size);
}
```

What is wrong with my code and how do I load an icon from the resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GResource` is not a file, but a binary resource bundled with your application/library. You should access it only with `g_resource_*()` methods or special methods which lookup data in resources, like `gtk_image_new_from_resource`, `gtk_builder_new_from_resource`, `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_resource`.

In your case you should have loaded `Gdkpixbuf` and set it as icon separately.

```c
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_resource ("/org/readaratus/decoder/app_icon", NULL);
gtk_window_set_icon (window, pixbuf);
```

Side note: if you have your icon hand-drawn in multiple sizes, use gtk_window_set_icon_list(). Then the best size will be used.